# Designing a custom PetaPoco mapper that supports HeadSprings Enumeration Class

Tags: c#, enumeration, petapoco

I'm attempting to create a mapper so PetaPoco can hydrate and persist POCOs with **Enumeration class** properties. See more about Enumeration classes [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/) or [here](https://github.com/HeadspringLabs/Enumeration).

For instance, Take this class.

```
    public class PetType : Headspring.Enumeration<PetType>
    {
       public static readonly PetType Frog = new PetType(1, "Frog");
       public static readonly PetType Cat = new PetType(2, "Cat");
       public static readonly PetType Fish = new PetType(3, "Fish");
       public static readonly PetType Dog = new PetType(4, "Dog");

       private PetType(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) { }
     }
```

Which can be used like so:

```
var MyPet = PetType.Dog;
```

Here is the Poco I want to hydrate/persist with the database:

```
    public class Pet
    {
         public int ID { get; set; }
         public string OwnerName { get; set; }
         public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
         public string PetName{ get; set; }
         public PetType PetType{ get; set; }
    }
```

I have designed a custom mapper that will work with PetType:

```
    class EnumClassMapper :  PetaPoco.StandardMapper 
    {
       public override Func<object, object> GetFromDbConverter(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo targetProperty, Type sourceType)
       {
           if (targetProperty.PropertyType == typeof(PetType))
           {
               return (x) => PetType.FromValue((int) x);
           }
           return base.GetFromDbConverter(targetProperty, sourceType);
       }

       public override Func<object, object> GetToDbConverter(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo sourceProperty)
       {
           if (sourceProperty.PropertyType == typeof(PetType))
           {
               return (x) => ((PetType)x).Value;
           }
           return base.GetToDbConverter(sourceProperty);
       }
   }
```

However suppose I create another Enumeration subclass for disposition.

```
    public class Disposition: Headspring.Enumeration<Disposition>
    {
       public static readonly Friendly = new Disposition(1, "Friendly");
       public static readonly Timid = new Disposition(2, "Timid");
       public static readonly Aggressive = new Disposition(3, "Aggressive");

       private Disposition(int value, string displayName) : base(value, displayName) { }
     }
```

I don't want to have to update my mapper every time I create a new subclass of the Enumeration class. I prefer that the mapping code could recognize that the property type is a descendent of the Enumeration class, and map accordingly. I assume the answer is to make use of reflection, but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
public class EnumClassMapper<T> :  PetaPoco.StandardMapper 
    where T : Headspring.Enumeration<T>   
{
   public override Func<object, object> GetFromDbConverter(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo targetProperty, Type sourceType)
   {
       return (x) => Enumeration<T, int>.FromValue((int) x);
   }

   public override Func<object, object> GetToDbConverter(System.Reflection.PropertyInfo sourceProperty)
   {
       return (x) => ((T)x).Value;
   }
}

var builder = DatabaseConfiguration.Build()
    .UsingConnectionStringName("sqlite")
    .UsingDefaultMapper<ConventionMapper>(m =>
    {
        m.FromDbConverter = (targetProperty, sourceType) =>
        {
            if (targetProperty == null)
                return null;

            var t = targetProperty.PropertyType;

                    if (t.BaseType == null || ! t.BaseType.IsGenericType) 
                        return null;

                    if (t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Headspring.Enumeration<>))
                        return null;

                    return ((IMapper)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EnumClassMapper<>).MakeGenericType(t))).GetFromDbConverter(targetProperty, sourceType);
        };
        m.ToDbConverter = sourceProperty =>
        {
            if (sourceProperty == null)
                return null;

            var t = sourceProperty.PropertyType;

                    if (t.BaseType == null || !t.BaseType.IsGenericType)
                        return null;

                    if (t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() != typeof(Headspring.Enumeration<>))
                        return null;

                    return ((IMapper)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(EnumClassMapper<>).MakeGenericType(t))).GetToDbConverter(sourceProperty);
        };
    });

var db = builder.Create();
```

Comment: You have a reference to "PetType" in your mapper class

Comment: Here : return (x) => PetType.FromValue((int) x);

Comment: and typeof(PetType).GetTypes() doesn't compile.

Comment: The type parameter in the Mapper.Register(type, IMapper) method is the type of the POCO class, not the type of the column it contains. There is an overload that will process any poco classes found in an assembly, but calling it multiple times just overwrites the previous mapper that was registered. I think the ForEach code has to be moved within the mapper class itself.

Comment: Updated to use fluent configuration. If it works, you may need to optimise it a little. I emphasised working over efficiency.

Comment: I made some changes to your post that ultimately solved my problem. Upvoting and marking as the correct answer.